# How to get A sequence of natural numbers, each number in a new line?

Tags: java

Given a sequence of natural numbers. For each number of the sequence output `even` if the number is even, otherwise, `odd`. If the number is equal to `0`, the program must stop reading and processing numbers.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int max = 0;
        int number = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            if (number % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("Odd");
                continue;
            } else if (number % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following problem:

- I can´t input a sequence of natural numbers, each number in a new line (see please the attachment. I can only input 2 numbers...

[image]

Failed test #1 of 9. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

**Test input:**

```
1
2
3
4
0
```

**Correct output:**

```
odd
even
odd
even
```

**Your code output:**

```
Odd
even
```

Comment: Why do you have a continue in the if block? And instead of e

Comment: So that it will continue if it is not zero.

Comment: No there's no need to have continue in if block. And you don't need else-if with any condition in the parenthesis, just "else" would suffice. And you can drop the "break" too as it's not a switch statement.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not break the condition when the number is even.
There should be another condition to check if `number = 0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            if(number == 0) {
                 break;
            }
            else if (number % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("odd");
            }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        if (num == 0)
            break;

        System.out.println(num % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    int number = 0;

    System.out.println("Start putting numbers");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        number = scanner.nextInt();
            if (number % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("Odd");
                continue;
            } else if (number % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("even");
            }
            if(number == 0)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Take care!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a typo in your code :)
Please, refactor the line:

```
System.out.println("Odd");
```

to

```
System.out.println("odd");
```

Also, you may not call the loop controls (break, continue) at all:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;

    while ((number = scanner.nextInt()) != 0) {
        if (number % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("odd");
        } else {
            System.out.println("even");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear :) Take care!